# Why can't distinct Youtube channels have also distinct URL?

Tags: youtube, google-drive

I have two GoogleDrive accounts and I wanted to create their two respective Youtube distinct accounts. The purpose for this, would be to have different content for my work and studies and have a better supervision and control upon my subscriptions etc.

The GoogleDrive accounts seem to function perfectly independent one with respect to another and I can keep working on both of them at the same time, without having to disconnect from anyone.

On the contrary, Youtube does not work this way. Although the accounts have different emails and they are not brand accounts, they cannot function independently. Every time i need to jump from the one to the other, the one gets disconnected.

How could they remain both on and processing at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On YouTube, when signed in to multiple accounts, you cannot use both at the same time. While you remain signed in to both accounts, YouTube sets one as the active account at a time. This is so that your watch history is logged to only one, and so your recommended videos for that account isn't influenced by other accounts signed in.

Say your buddy signed in on your computer. You wouldn't want him watching a video to influence your recommended.

So in order to use the account not set as active, you have to press the icon at the top, [image: icon] and press switch accounts.

[image: switch]

Then select the account you want to use.

The inactive account should not get disconnected unless you're pressing sign out instead of switch account.